Runs of Integers Sharing a Factor with $n$
While doing a repeated, monotonous task $n$ times, I like to pass time by calculating the exact fraction of my job that I've completed in least terms. Sometimes, I get long runs where the denominator is smaller than $n$, which is cool. Sometimes, I encounter lone
So let $R(n)$ be the longest run of consecutive integers which share a factor with $n$. We can restrict ourselves to looking at $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ because the pattern repeats modulo $n$.
For instance, tonight I had to grade $n=42$ homework submissions. I had a run of length 5 at one point, consisting of $6,7,8,9,10$, all of which share a factor with $42$. So $R(42) = 5$.
It's clear that $R(n)=R(s)$ where $s$ is the product of $n$'s distinct prime factors. This is because a number shares a factor with $n$ iff it shares a factor with $s$.
Q: Is there a formula or asymptotic bound for $R(n)$?

This is one less than the “Jacobsthal function”, the OEIS page of which is one entry point to what we know about it. Iwaniec (On the problem of Jacobsthal, Demonstratio Math. 11 (1978), no. 1, 225–231) proved that there's some constant $C>0$ such that if $n$ has $k$ distinct prime factors then $R(n) < Ck^2\log^2k$.
